# To check the entries of two files iterativley with a third file in python

Tags: python, file

I have two files namely fu and fp to store the ip and urls respectively. I need to count the number of times the user has requested certain page and store in a two dimensional dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
fu_file=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/fu','r')
fp_file=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/fp','r')
cleaned_file=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/clean_web_log','r')
access = defaultdict(dict)
for user in fu_file:
    for page in fp_file:
         count=0
         for line in cleaned_file:
              line_words=line.split()
              if user[:-1]==line_words[1]:
                  if page[:-1]==line_words[2]:
                       count +=1
              access[user][page]=count
cleaned_file.close()
fp_file.close()
fu_file.close()
```

The clean_web_log has three entries size ip url.
The fu file has one entry ip with a new line character and has 75 entries
The fp file has one entry page_url with a new line character and has 915 entries

When i execute this , only first entry of fu_file is entered, the iteration doesnt go through the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you read a file object directly, like this:

```
for page in fp_file:
```

The file can only be read once. You need to store the file contents in a list if you want to read it multiple times.

```
pages = list(fp_file.readlines())

for user in fu_file:
    for page in pages:
```

Same thing with `cleaned_file`.

Comment: thank you!! is there any way I can make it perform better, cause it takes nearly five minutes to process

Comment: @PrasannaKumar Maybe, but you need to provide some examples of the contents of the three files. You should post a new question about it.